# IIS 10's Central W3C logging and file names

Tags: logging, iis-10

Is there a way to append a prefix to file names when using Central W3C log mode (one log per server) in IIS 10?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be such flexibility.

Comment: Thanks. Whilst searching, I came across Advanced Logging which supposedly allow me to provide a base file name for log files. I even found an installer for it. However, the installation fails with "IIS version 7.0 is required". I'm assuming it's deprecated?

Comment: Advanced Logging module is considered deprecated for IIS 10 and above. I had a personal blog post on that https://blog.lextudio.com/status-of-iis-out-of-band-modules-80a3af57c489

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to install advanced log in IIS 10, you may get error because IIS 10 is not considered as a higher version of IIS 7.

This is a known issue.

Please remember to modify registry:

**Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\MajorVersion** from **10** to **9**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting! I wonder if this is gonna interfere somehow with IIS's operation in any way

Comment: @AmirKeibi We have monitored this operation for a long period of time and it has no side effect or  interference on IIS's operation

Comment: Thanks. This is certainly useful.